# Git/GitHub: not accept passphrase after restart the system

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm new in git/github and I'm having trouble cloning my own test repository. I added a ssh key to my account with the steps:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@gmail.com"
Asks me in which file I want to save the key and I choose 'git_guilherme-key'
mv git_guilherme-key ~/.ssh/
mv git_guilherme-key.pub ~/.ssh/
ssh-add ~/.ssh/git_guilherme-key
```

I created theses files because the files "id_ed25519" and "id_ed25519.pub" already have a key for another git account.

On the github I clicked on "Settings->SSH and GPG keys->New SSH key" and pasted on it the content of:
cat ~/.ssh/git_guilherme-key.pub

After all theses steps if I create a repository and clone it with "git clone " everything works fine. But if I restart the system, login into github and try to clone the same repository, i get:

```
Cloning into 'webpage'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/guilherme/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/guilherme/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/guilherme/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix this? I'm using Linux by the way.

Comment: I think you need to do the ssh-add again after a reboot. That only has effect on the running instance of ssh agent.

Comment: It workid but how can I add it automatically?

Comment: Or you can configure your .ssh/config to consider more keys. https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config <- IdentityFile?

Answer (score 0):

> It worked but how can I add it automatically?

You cannot, unless you:

- [start ssh-agent through your `.bashrc` or `.profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/7490)
- make a script which passes your passphrase (see previous link, but that is not a good idea, as the private key is no longer really protected: its passphrase would be in clear in your script)

For a personal usage, just for GitHub access, you can also consider creating your dedicate private key *without* passphrase.